# Firebase - Android No executable code found

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to add firebase to my project but when I add the declaration of ref variable it says the line 400 is no executable code. Why?

[image]

Comment: instead of putting snapshot of code, why not put your activity code itself ?

Comment: can you be a little more specific?

Comment: can you put your whole activity code ?

Answer (score 0):

```
        DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("your Reference");
```

and then use ref.setValue();